# importing an excel file to python

Tags: python, import-from-excel

I have a basic question about importing xlsx files to Python. I have checked many responses about the same topic, however I still cannot import my files to Python whatever I try. Here's my code and the error I receive:

```
import pandas as pd

import xlrd

file_location = 'C:\Users\cagdak\Desktop\python_self_learning\Coursera\sample_data.xlsx'
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
```

**Error:**

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\cagdak\\Desktop\\python_self_learning\\Coursera\\sample_data.xlsx'
```

Comment: Your problem is that the file is not found, not a problem of importing: verify that the file is at the path you think it's at.

Comment: Hint: Did you verify that the xlsx file does exist in the location ?

Comment: Yes, it does. I am copying the folder path here : C:\Users\cagdak\Desktop\python_self_learning\Coursera and the name of the excel file is : sample_data

Answer (score 23):

With pandas it is possible to get directly a column of an Excel file. Here is the code.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('sample.xls')

#print the column names
print df.columns

#get the values for a given column
values = df['column_name'].values

#get a data frame with selected columns
FORMAT = ['Col_1', 'Col_2', 'Col_3']
df_selected = df[FORMAT]
```

Comment: Thanks but I still receive "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory " error although I am 100% sure the file location and file name is correct. I spent almost 3 hours to do this.

Comment: Also need to do `pip install xlrd`

Answer (score 3):

You should use [raw strings or escape your backslash](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) instead, for example:

```
file_location = r'C:\Users\cagdak\Desktop\python_self_learning\Coursera\sample_data.xlsx'
```

or

```
file_location = 'C:\\Users\\cagdak\\Desktop\python_self_learning\\Coursera\\sample_data.xlsx'
```

Comment: @CagdasKanar Do you have read access to the file? What happens if you run `python -c "import os; print(os.stat(r'C:\Users\cagdak\Desktop\python_self_learning\Coursera\sample_data.xlsx'))"` ?

Comment: Should I run this on notebook or terminal?

Comment: In a terminal for that exact command. If you still get a "file not found" error, I suspect the file just isn't where you think it is, or you don't have access to that file for python to read it.

Answer (score 1):

go ahead and try this:

```
file_location = 'C:/Users/cagdak/Desktop/python_self_learning/Coursera/sample_data.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above Pandas supports reading of Excel spreadsheets using its [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) method. However, it is dependent upon a number of external libraries depending on which version Excel/odf is being accessed. It defaults to selecting one automatically, though one can be specified using the `engine` parameter. Here's an excerpt from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

> ```
> "xlrd" supports old-style Excel files (.xls).
> "openpyxl" supports newer Excel file formats.
> "odf" supports OpenDocument file formats (.odf, .ods, .odt).
> "pyxlsb" supports Binary Excel files.
> ```

If the required library is not already installed you'll see an error message suggesting library you need to install.